# Switching user in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, switch-user

I am switching users in `laravel` and I succeeded in that as well but the thing is when I redirect the user to the dashboard after successful login it redirects to login form instead I don't know what am I doing wrong. Here is the code I am using.

```
public function user_reauthenticate(Request $request) {
    $input = Input::all();
    $data = User::where('email', $input['email'])->first();
    if ($data) {
        if (Hash::check($input['password'], $data->password)) {
            Session::put('email', $input['email']);
            $newuser = Student::find($input['new_user']);
            session(['orig_user' => $data->id]);
            Auth::login($newuser);
            return Redirect::back();
        } else {
            $response = 'Wrong Credentials';
        }
    } else {
        $response = 'User does not exist';
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me find out the issue?

Comment: You need to use auth attempts

Comment: Auth attempts where

Comment: you are redirecting back like this `return Redirect::back();` so it will navigate to login form only.

Comment: php artisan make:auth is really cool :D automated login/registration

Comment: check the answer below.

Comment: Why just not utlize the php artisan make:auth command then override the methods there.

Answer (score 0):

## Edited

You can log in with

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

New edited

```
// If you have the guard student and multiple auth
$auth = auth()->guard('student');
$objAuth = $auth->loginUsingId($input['new_user']);

//Single Auth

$objAuth = Auth::loginUsingId($input['new_user']);
```

Comment: Nope tried this solution as well it is still redirecting me to login from

Comment: $input['new_user'] I hope in this you have Id of student ?

Comment: Yes in this I have the id of that user on whose account user needs to be switched\

Comment: sir when I do `dd(Auth::user()->id);` I get the id of new user on which I need to switched but it always redirect back to login Form

Comment: are you using multiple auth ?

Comment: Yes I am using multi auth one is User table and the other one is Student table

Comment: @MohsinAbbas Why just create a role_id that referes to the roles table in the users table and just query it up there. Like if the user's role_id is 1 then it is a user then if it's 2 then it's student. That would be the most efficient apporach

Comment: @d3cypher sir I just can't because database is provided by client and I just can't change anything in the database

Comment: Well, in that case, do u provide only a single form / 2 login forms based on your users.

Comment: @d3cypher sir there are 2 login forms one for users and second one for students

Comment: On that case it would be easy for you just use the Auth::attempt

Comment: if Auth::attempt(array $credentials = [], bool $remember = false, bool $login = true){ 

// condition here 

}@MohsinAbbas

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your top of the file:- `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;`

Afterwards add a `if` function like below in your already completed code:-

```
public function user_reauthenticate(Request $request)
{
     use AuthenticatesUsers;
     $input = Input::all();
     $data = User::where('email', $input['email'])->first();
     if ($data) {
     if (Hash::check($input['password'], $data->password))
     {
        Session::put('email', $input['email']);
        $newuser = Student::find($input['new_user']);
        session(['orig_user' => $data->id]);
        Auth::login($newuser);
        if ($this->attemptLogin($request))
        {
             return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
     }
     else
     {
          $response = 'Wrong Credentials';
     }
 }
     else
     {
          $response = 'User does not exist';
     }
}
```

After this method override this method as follows:-

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{   
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');   
}
```

Check whether your dashboard route is named dashboard or if not name it.

Comment: Nope it still redirects me back to login form instead of dashboard